# How to combine custom hooks and selector results?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a custom hook and also have some selectors and need a final flag to be set based on a combination of the two.
I can't simply write a function that combines the code below cos neither hooks or selectors can be used outside a react FC

What's the best way to make the whole block like this a single reusable function somewhere?

```
// selector
    const { activeIntents, writeRole, intents, permalink } = useSelector(state => state.companyIntentsReducer);
// custom hook
    const { hasExtendedRoleForCompany } = useJwtRoles();
// func calling the custom hook
    const intentWrite = hasExtendedRoleForCompany("intent-manage-write", permalink);
// final result combines both
    const editMode = writeRole && intentWrite
```

can custom hooks use selectors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write a [custom hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html), something like:

```
const useEditMode = () => {
  const { activeIntents, writeRole, intents, permalink } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.companyIntentsReducer
  );

  const { hasExtendedRoleForCompany } = useJwtRoles();
  const intentWrite = hasExtendedRoleForCompany(
    "intent-manage-write",
    permalink
  );

  return { isEditMode: writeRole && intentWrite };
};

export default useEditMode;

// Usage inside function component
const { isEditMode } = useEditMode();
```

Comment: great so custom hooks CAN use redux selectors?

Comment: Custom hooks CAN use [redux-hooks](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks) (like `useSelector`). Don't know what "use redux selectors" means, "selectors" are pure functions passed to `useSelector` and in `mapDispatchToProps` etc.

Comment: by `use redux selector` i was referring to the common practive `useSelector from "react-redux";`  resulting often in `React Hook "useSelector" is called in function "x" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function. ` when actually used. But you've basically answered the question

Comment: So yes, no problem

Comment: When writing a custom hook you have to use `use` prefix `useCustom`, `useX` or the lint rule will pop-up.

Comment: so `use.*` is the extent of the check there? I thought some other magic code parsing was going on. How does it know you aren't coding a react FC? similar regex tricks?

Comment: React FC must to be uppercased and return JSX element, custom hook must use prefix, no magic parsing just redex